# Multi-label classification with frequencies - NLP (BERT)

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I have dataset that looks like this:

```
entence          emotions
bla bla bla       {'kind':105, 'sad':32, 'angry':5}
.....             {'surprised': 65, 'kind': 10}
```

Numbers here represents how many times people had this emotion while reading the post

Basically, post *'bla bla bla'* seemed *'kind'* to 105 people while 32 people felt *'sad'* about it.

Basically, my goal is to predict a type of emotion a post most likely to have

I am going to use a BERT transformer.

Question: How to deal with the frequency that each emotion has? I know that frequency is important especially when one post has 105 people that smiled and the other 5 felt angry and if I remove frequency then it would be smile and angry together and that can cause misunderstanding. How should I design my model? Should I just remove frequency? or should I remove all the other emotion type except for the one that has the most frequency?

Comment: In my opinion, if your purpose is to predict only the emotion that has the highest number, I don't know what all the frequencies could do for you. So I would tell you to remove and keep only the one with the highest value.

Comment: You can normalize the frequencies, and train your model for multi-label regression.